# Can we add a summary to documentation topics

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I recently noticed that some simple examples in the documentation also include a summary of the topic. It gets weird when some of the short examples get upvoted more than the example with the summary so that the summary ends up in the middle of the page. For an example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/16/verbatim-strings#t=201607221236558368228

I'm thinking it would be better with a separate summary section at the top or a sticky order of the examples. What do you think?

Comment: This should be what the "Remarks" section is for. It should possibly be relabeled "Summary" and definitely go at the top.