# How to place a text to a main body of a topic without any subsection?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

Right now there is 4 predefined sections in each topic:

- Examples
- Syntax
- Parameters
- Remarks

So, we start with examples without giving any information about topic itself.

For instance, let's take [Java Arrays topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays):

[image]

We have a bunch of examples, but what is array in Java, actually? What it's used for?

Some people place this info to `Remarks` section, but this is inconvenient for general info.

Comment: One of the most popular requests since the introduction of docs. The team seems to remain unconvinced. Not sure why. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328620/documentation-should-have-an-initial-section, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328959/can-we-add-a-summary-to-documentation-topics, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328431/add-optional-synopsis-for-a-topic

Comment: Ok, thanks to mark it as duplicate, did not find this feature request.

Comment: No worries. It would be pretty incredible if you did. There are thousands of bugs and feature requests related to Documentation flooding into Meta. :-)